# How do you implement a view object in a partial in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a view which loops through a partial like so:

```
- @pages.each do |page|
          = render 'page_item', page: page, disable_nesting: true
```

I want to implement a view object for the presentation of `'page_item'` partial.

I know best practice for view objects is to instantiate them at the end of the controller action, but in this case that won't be possible, because the action applies to the parent view rather than the partial `'page_item'`.

Where should I instantiate this view object?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a presenter for the Parent model that builds the child presenters for you when you call a method:

```
# parent_presenter.rb

class ParentPresenter

  attr_reader :parent

  def initialize(parent)
    @parent = parent
  end

  def page_presenters
    parent.pages.map { |page| PagePresenter.new(page) }
  end
end
```

You will need a separate presenter for the Page model:

```
# page_presenter.rb

class PagePresenter

  attr_reader :page

  def initialize(page)
    @page = page
  end

  def presenter_method
    # Presentation logic here
  end
end
```

Your controller action looks like this:

```
# parents_controller.rb

class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
    @parent_presenter = ParentPresenter.new(parent)
  end
end
```

Now from your view, you can do:

```
- @parent_presenter.page_presenters.each do |page_presenter|
      = render 'page_item', presenter: page_presenter, disable_nesting: true
```